# Android PinIt sharing doesn't show description with URI source

Tags: android, pinterest, pin-it-sdk

I'm using PinIt Class (Android PinIt SDK) to post an image on Pinterest.

When I post an online image by URL, image shows up in dialog popup as well as suggested description, everything is fine.

By adjusting code to use URI as source file instead, only selected file is being shown, but no description.

**I need to show my own suggested description while using URI, how do I achieve it?**

Code (image as URL - description works):

```
PinIt.setDebugMode(true);
PinIt.setPartnerId(CLIENT_ID);

pinIt = new PinIt();
pinIt.setImageUrl("http://placekitten.com/500/400");
pinIt.setUrl("http://placekitten.com");
pinIt.setDescription("post description");
pinIt.setListener(_listener);
pinIt.doPinIt(this);
```

RESULT:

[image: image as URL]
  _

Code (image as URI - suggested description doesn't work):

```
PinIt.setDebugMode(true);
PinIt.setPartnerId(CLIENT_ID);

pinIt = new PinIt();
pinIt.setImageUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Pictures/401600717.jpg")));
pinIt.setUrl("http://placekitten.com");
pinIt.setDescription("post description");
pinIt.setListener(_listener);
pinIt.doPinIt(this);
```

RESULT:

[image: image as URI]

*tried to remove pinIt.setUrl, didnt work either

Comment: HI, can you provide example? I need example of pinterest sharing..

Comment: Jakaob : vat is in doPinIt??